# Generic View Not able to load and throws TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use the Generic views in Django. This is a part of the tutorial on the official Django site. I've been at this problem for a few hours now and somehow the other answers on this website and others don't seem to solve my problem.

The index.html file is working as localhost:8000/polls loads successfully but anything after that throws the TemplateDoesNotExist error. I don't know why when it tries to load a Generic view, it fails. I also tried removing the index.html file but still the Generic View failed to load

I'll probably put up everything of concern here:

My settings.py file:

```
import os

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))





DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( "C:/Django/mysite/templates/polls/",  )

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'






DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'pankaj29',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My views.py file is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    #template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

My urls.py file is:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

My files structure is:

[image: File Struct]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have a `results.html` or `detail.html`

Comment: `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` haven’t been used since Django 1.8 - I would avoid any book or tutorial that is using them, because it is out of date. You can remove them from the settings because they won’t have any effect.

Comment: It’s not a good idea to post your password and secret key in Stack Overflow. Make sure you change these values before you deploy your site, and if you use that password anywhere else then change it for a longer password that is harder to crack.

Comment: But as Iain says, you only have an index template, so it's not clear how you are expecting the detail or results pages to work.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for the advice. WIll keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the concept wasn't clear to me. I thought Generic Views meant a bunch of views that were inbuilt in Django much like the admin page that is built into Django. But actually, Generic Views are just specific views that are made Generic *for the app* as opposed to any inbuilt views. Leaving this question here for anybody who has the same problem.